# Include() with Wheres clause failing

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

This is strange, could anyone try to explain my why this is working just fine:

```
_db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Category).ThenInclude(c => c.ApplicationUser)
                .ToList();
```

while this throws exception:

```
_db.Tasks.Include(t=>t.Category).ThenInclude(c=>c.ApplicationUser)
                .Where(t => t.Category.ApplicationUser.UserName == username)
                .ToList();
```

For some reason .Include() does not work with .Where clause. Any ideas?

The exception:

```
   at lambda_method(Closure , InternalEntityEntry )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.SimpleNonNullableDependentKeyValueFactory`1.TryCreateFromCurrentValues(InternalEntityEntry entry, TKey& key)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.WeakReferenceIdentityMap`1.CreateIncludeKeyComparer(INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.IncludeCore(Object entity, INavigation navigation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.Include(QueryContext queryContext, Object entity, IReadOnlyList`1 navigationPath, IReadOnlyList`1 relatedEntitiesLoaders, Int32 currentNavigationIndex, Boolean queryStateManager)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.Include(QueryContext queryContext, Object entity, IReadOnlyList`1 navigationPath, IReadOnlyList`1 relatedEntitiesLoaders, Boolean queryStateManager)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.GroupJoinInclude.Include(Object entity)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_GroupJoin>d__26`4.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__163`3.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__15`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at _:line 56
```

generated sql that is working just fine when executed against Sql Server:

```
SELECT [t].[TaskId], [t].[CategoryId], [t].[Description], [t].[Name], [t].[Timestamp], [t.Category].[CategoryId], [t.Category].[Description], [t.Category].[Name], [t.Category].[Timestamp], [t.Category].[UserId], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[Id], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[AccessFailedCount], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[ConcurrencyStamp], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[Email], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[EmailConfirmed], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[LockoutEnabled], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[LockoutEnd], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[NormalizedEmail], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[NormalizedUserName], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[PasswordHash], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[PhoneNumber], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[SecurityStamp], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[TwoFactorEnabled], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[UserName], [c].[CategoryId], [c].[Description], [c].[Name], [c].[Timestamp], [c].[UserId], [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName]
FROM [Tasks] AS [t]
INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [t.Category] ON [t].[CategoryId] = [t.Category].[CategoryId]
LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [t.Category.ApplicationUser] ON [t.Category].[UserId] = [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [c] ON [t].[CategoryId] = [c].[CategoryId]
LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a] ON [c].[UserId] = [a].[Id]
ORDER BY [t.Category].[UserId]
```

Models:

```
public class Task
{
    [Key]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception? And, what version of EF are you using?

Comment: Show your `Category` and `ApplicationUser`

Comment: It is EF Core, exception attached

Comment: You're only showing the stack trace. Show the full exception message

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Isn't the answer to these always DefaultIfEmpty() ??

Comment: It is not empty, that is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to resolve the issue after half day wasted. I was not able to achieve the desired results with .Include() and .Where(), but this is what have worked for me. Please let me know if you find a way to make it work with .Include() and .Where(), since I am very curious:

```
return _db.Tasks
                    .Where(t => t.Category.ApplicationUser.UserName == username)
                    .Select(t => new
                    {
                        t,
                        t.Category
                    })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(t => t.t)
                    .ToList();
```